# Why can't easy_install find MySQLdb?

Tags: python, mysql, easy-install

This is what I tried:

```
$ easy_install-2.6 -d /home/user/lib/python2.6 MySQLdb  
Searching for MySQLdb  
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQLdb/  
Couldn't find index page for 'MySQLdb' (maybe misspelled?)  
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)  
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/  
No local packages or download links found for MySQLdb  
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('MySQLdb')
```

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You have the wrong package name.

[MySQL-python](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/) is the right one:

```
easy_install MySQL-python
```

or

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

Comment: I looks like this is currently installing MySQL-python 1.2.2, which does not contain MySQLdb 1.2.3

Comment: I have been working with `MySQLdb` but now it seems to be unavilable. Does MySQL-python containes MySQLdb? Or I have to change my code?

Comment: Somebody know why this happened? 
ERROR: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Answer (score 8):

Adam is right but before you run `easy_install MySQL-python` you need to make sure `python-dev` is installed as it is not installed by default.

Install is with `apt-get install python-dev`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using "yum" the command is `sudo yum install python-devel` (where 'sudo' may be optional depending on your user account)