# How to install MySQLdb in Python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I tied install `MySQLdb` package using command: `pip install MySQLdb` in Windows 7 (64bit). After I get error:

```
could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQLdb
```

I tried to do this using `easy`.  I get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx2vR.png)

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047848/why-cant-easy-install-find-mysqldb)

Comment: I tried this using `easy` I get error, see attachment in question

Comment: That's a completely different error which has been also answered several times. [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: mysqldb isn't available for Python 3.